# Поиск товаров по их характеристикам

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Добрый вечер(или день).
Столкнулся с проблемой филтрации товар по их характеристикам. 
Для начала опишу структуру бд:

```
Таблица товара (tbl_good)
id name

Таблица характеристик(tbl_attr)
id name

Таблица значений характеристик (tbl_attr_value)
id value   attr_id(внешний клюк на таблицу характеристик)

Связывающая Таблица (tbl_good_attr_value)
id  good_id  value_id attr_id
Соответственно внешний ключи на выше указанные таблицы
```

Мне нужно отфильтровать товары по значения их характеристик. Например:
мне нужно выбрать кросовки у которых только цвет синий, материал кожа и тд..

Вот код которым я все это выбираю:

```
 SELECT g.name FROM tbl_good as g
 JOIN tbl_good_attr_value as gav ON gav.good_id = g.id 
 WHERE g.price <= :max_price AND g.price >= :min_price 
 AND (gav.attr_id="7" AND gav.value_id IN ("503")) 
 OR (gav.attr_id="8" AND gav.value_id IN ("539"))
```

Но проблема в том  что мне выводит все товари у которых хотя бы одна из выбраных характеристики имееться, а мне нужно что бы точное совпадение было.
Где ошибка?

Comment: @Mike - SELECT g.name FROM tbl_good as g
 JOIN tbl_good_attr_value as gav ON gav.good_id = g.id 
 WHERE g.price <= :max_price AND g.price >= :min_price 
 AND (gav.attr_id="7" AND gav.value_id IN ("503")) 
 OR (gav.attr_id="8" AND gav.value_id IN ("539")) having count(gav.attr_id)=2 тоже самое =/

Comment: Перед having `group by g.id, g.name` надо добавить. Вообще странно как может быть "то же самое". having без group by свернет все до одной записи

Comment: Если нужно чтобы совпадали все характеристики, то нужно применять операцию `AND`. `OR`-же выбирает или то или другое (и т.д.). `AND` - `И`, `OR` - `ИЛИ`. Чуйствуюте разницу между `синие и кожаные` и `синие или кожаные`? Если да, то какого ... там OR?

Comment: @Sergey Вот с OR там как раз все верно. Ибо эти поля в разных записях лежат. И по вашему получится "выбери мне записи в которых attr_id равен 7 И одновременно равен 8"

Comment: OR  в даном  случае  нужен  если в выбрано 2 или  боле  значений характеристик одной  и тойже  характеристики.Если же ставлю AND, вообще  ничего  не находить

Comment: @YuriiChmil Кстати стоит числовые поля не заключать в кавычки. Бывают с ними приколы ... Кстати, в итоге group by помог или нет ?

Comment: Вот рабочий тест http://ideone.com/rZWZ4F  Заменил count(1) на `count(distinct gav.attr_id)` на случай если у вас у одного товара может быть несколько значений для одного атрибута

Comment: @Mike - спасибо работает! Правда теперь не корретно считает количество результата - мне нужно это для пагинации. Можете что то предложить?) Считает так: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) FROM tbl_good as g
JOIN tbl_good_attr_value as gav ON gav.good_id = g.id WHERE g.price <= :max_price AND g.price >= :min_price AND( (gav.attr_id="7" AND gav.value_id IN ("459")) OR (gav.attr_id="8" AND gav.value_id IN ("536")) OR (gav.attr_id="9" AND gav.value_id IN ("572")) )

Comment: @YuriiChmil Сделайте `select count(1) from (тот запрос, которым выбирали товары) X` http://ideone.com/vRJkDr

Comment: @Mike спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.id, g.name 
FROM tbl_good as g
INNER JOIN tbl_good_attr_value as gav ON gav.good_id = g.id 

WHERE g.price <= :max_price AND g.price >= :min_price 
AND (
    (gav.attr_id="7" AND gav.value_id IN ("503")) 
    OR (gav.attr_id="8" AND gav.value_id IN ("539")) 
)
```

вроде так

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но нет, тогда вообще ничего не находит. В запросе attr_id - ето идетификатор характеристики(цвет или материал) а value_id - соответственно иї значения( черный, кожа и тд)

Comment: ааа, пардон, невнимательно посмотрел... минутку...

Comment: обновил запрос в ответе

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.name 
  FROM tbl_good as g
  JOIN tbl_good_attr_value as с ON с.good_id = g.id AND с.attr_id="7" -- color
  JOIN tbl_good_attr_value as m ON m.good_id = g.id AND m.attr_id="8" -- material
 WHERE g.price <= :max_price AND g.price >= :min_price 
   AND c.value_id IN ("503")
   AND m.value_id IN ("539")
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но по моему это не самый лучший вариант - поскольку для каждой новой характеристики нужно делать новый JOIN

Comment: Кто будет привередничать, тот останется вообще без результата. Тем более другого варианта и нету в общем-то. Хотя можете написать хранимую процедуру, в которой происходит циклическая проверка всех отобранных характеристик. Но это уже немного не SQL.

Comment: @Sergey Так результат уже есть, он дан первым же моим комментарием под ответом (о дубле) и уже опробован ТС и работает :) И когда надо проверить десяток атрибутов десять join тяжко ...

Comment: @Mike Хороший вариант. Просто замечательный. Только формулировки вопросов такие, что ни вопросы ни тем более ответ не найдёт никто.

Comment: @Sergey Это общая проблема всех вопросов по SQL, сформулировать вопрос так что бы потом он нашелся нереально, особенно учитывая что задающий новый вопрос формулирует по своему и даже красиво сформулированный старый не найдет. Я то когда дубли ищу, помню, на что уже отвечал и ищу среди своих ответов по ключевым словам которые в ответе (в данном случае having)